# Access a link from outside a branch.io callback function?

Tags: angularjs, deep-linking, branch.io

I want to create a link of a webpage to share on facebook (and others). 
I'm using branch.io web SDK in an angularJS project.

```
 function shareFacebook(){

    branch.link({
        tags: [ 'tag1', 'tag2' ],
        channel: 'facebook',
        feature: 'dashboard',
        stage: 'new user',
        data: {
           mydata: 'something',
           foo: 'bar',
           '$desktop_url': $location.absUrl(),
           '$og_image_url': 'http://branch.io/img/logo_icon_white.png'
        }
    }, function(err, link) {
        console.log(err, link);
    });

    //I want to return the link here
}
```

The link is created, but how can i access to it from outside callback function?

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch.io here:

This is not a question specifically about Branch — this has to do with the fundamental nature of callbacks and asynchronous code execution in javascript. Basically, you can't directly access the value of `link` outside of the callback function the way you have it written currently because there is no guarantee that `branch.link()` will have executed yet, and therefore `link` may not have a value.

**Easiest option:** do whatever it you need inside the callback function.

**Harder option:** Read more about asynchronous code flow and come up with an alternative structure. Without seeing the details of what you are trying to do with `link`, it's impossible to offer a more specific solution.